# How do I install apt-get from Debian source[no dpkg]

Tags: debian, apt-get

I am able to find the source for aptitude on Debian's package manager. ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/aptitude

I plan to install dpkg on to a stripped down embedded linux but it suggests to use apt-get to install dpkg. Well apt-get is not on the machine either. But most of the solution involves use dpkg -i on the deb file. It seems like a chicken and egg problem. Is there a way to install apt-get from source without dpkg? The target machine is a aarch64 architecture.

Comment: Perhaps better to post it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/aptitude : The last line is `aptitude_0.8.7.orig.tar.xz`. ... Besides that, all packages *and* the **source** is available on the "search page" https://packages.debian.org/stretch/aptitude → aarch64 package → **arm64**. ... About `dpkg` : apt and aptitude are using `dpkg` to install packages.